# JSON unmarshalling single element arrays

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I am using Jersey: 2.9.1 and `MOXyJsonProvider` configured as follows:

```
@Provider
public class MOXyJsonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

  private final MoxyJsonConfig config;

  public MOXyJsonContextResolver() {
    config = new MoxyJsonConfig();
    config.setAttributePrefix("");
    config.setValueWrapper("value");
    config.property(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, true);
  }

  @Override
  public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
    return config;
  }
}
```

I have a Company class having collection of addresses:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "addresses")
  @XmlElement(name = "address")
  private Collection<Address> addresses;
  ...
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address{
  private String street;
  private String city;
  private String country;
  ...
}
```

The problem is that marshalled object having a single element array can not be unmarshalled properly. For instance: if I ask my web service for a company object I will get something like that:

```
"company" : { "addresses":[{ "city" : "Warszawa",  "street" : "Testowa", "country" : "Polska"}]}
```

Correct. but if I passed this to my web service again as an argument then on the web service side I would get a company having an empty array.

For arrays having more than one element everything works as expected.

**UPDATE**

I have moved the problem here:
[JAXBMarshaller and JAXBUnmarshaller are not compatible with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910193/jaxbmarshaller-and-jaxbunmarshaller-are-not-compatible)

You can find there a simplified version of this one and a real jUnit test case that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the Addresses as an ArrayList. Also define as a List, not Collection.

```
private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

We do something very similar without problem

Comment: nothing has changed :(

Comment: How about the @XmlRootElement annotation on address. Is an address a root element in another context? Maybe try removing that.

Comment: I have moved my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910193/jaxbmarshaller-and-jaxbunmarshaller-are-not-compatible

Comment: There is a concrete test case that fails

Comment: no, still the same result