# JAXBMarshaller and JAXBUnmarshaller are not compatible with each other

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

JAXBMarshaller and JAXBUnmarshaller are not compatible when I try to use an object containing a single element array and JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME is set to TRUE. I have this problem when I use Jersey 2.9.1 and Moxy is set as JSON provider. To simplify this case I have checked in the debugger which classes are used and created a single test case:

I am marshalling an object to a string and then this string is passed to Unmarshaller. Surprisingly the resulting object is different from the input object.

Beans:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "children")
  @XmlElement(name = "child")
  private Collection<Child> children;

  public Collection<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

  public void setChildren(Collection<Child> children) {
    this.children = children;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Parent [children=%s]", children);
  }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {

  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Child [name=%s]", name);
  }
}
```

Test Case:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties;
...

@Test
  public void jsonTest() throws JAXBException {

    boolean wrapperAsArrayName = true;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { Parent.class }, null);
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.setChildren(new ArrayList<Child>());
    Child child1 = new Child();
    child1.setName("Marek");
    parent.getChildren().add(child1);

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, wrapperAsArrayName);

    OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    marshaller.marshal(parent, baos);

    String marshalled = baos.toString();
    System.out.println(marshalled);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, wrapperAsArrayName);

    InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(marshalled.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Parent result = (Parent)unmarshaller.unmarshal(bais);
    System.out.println(result);
    assertEquals(result.getChildren().size(), parent.getChildren().size());
  }
```

Results:
JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME= true:

```
{"parent":{"children":[{"name":"Marek"}]}}
Parent [children=[]]
java.lang.AssertionError
```

JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME= false:

```
{"parent":{"children":{"child":[{"name":"Marek"}]}}}
Parent [children=[Child [name=Marek]]]
```

No problem for collections having more than one element:

```
{"parent":{"children":[{"name":"Marek"},{"name":"Marek2"}]}}
Parent [children=[Child [name=Marek], Child [name=Marek2]]]

{"parent":{"children":{"child":[{"name":"Marek"},{"name":"Marek2"}]}}}
Parent [children=[Child [name=Marek], Child [name=Marek2]]]
```

Comment: Yes, that is the same case, thank you :D To solve the problem I had to remove old moxy libraries(2.5.0) from my brand new Jersey 2.10.1 :) and add new ones (2.5.2).